# After replacing PERC H310 with PERC H710P the Dell BIOS (and Ubuntu installer) refuses to recognize any (non-raid) physical drives

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We had a H310 Mini Mono controller in a completely non-raid configuration and had it replaced with a H710P controller. The controller is installed in a Dell Poweredge r620 system.

We have 4 drives attached in a non-raid configuration and the new H710P controller recognizes all the physical drives in the PERC configuration utility (Ctrl+R) and they are all listed as READY

The Dell BIOS however does not list any of the drives or the PERC controller itself on the UEFI Boot settings screen (F2 -> Bios). If we boot from a USB stick into Ubuntu installer none of the drives are recognized as present on the system.

The PERC H710P firmware version is 21.3.5-0002 which I can't quite figure out whether is up to date or not - should I try upgrading the firmware?

I am confused as to why the physical drives are no longer exposed to the system and are only visible in the PERC controller bios. This configuration worked with the old card, but maybe the H710P expects/needs you to set up virtual disks before exposing any accessible/bootable devices to the rest of the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H710 does not support non-RAID disks (sometimes known as pass-through)

Each disk must be part of a Virtual Disk, even if it is a single-disk RAID 0.

Comment: I can confirm this is the correct answer - adding the drives to single-disk RAID 0 enables the BIOS and any OS to detect the drives. I was not aware of the pass-through limitation, but suspected it in the end. Thanks for your help @Bert

Comment: Note that it is now possible to flash the H710P Mini to IT mode to allow non-RAID/JBOD/passthrough.